# Javascript function stops after first while loop in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have some javascript that creates a datetime picker on each row of a table. The function only works on the first row. I understand that the reason for this is that the datepicker shares the same ID on every row. How can I adjust my code to fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#duedate').datetimepicker({
controlType: 'select',
timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
});
});
</script>

<?php $txtJob = $_GET['pickjob']; ?>

<?php
$query2 = "Select Work_Center, Sequence, Est_Total_Hrs from V_schedule WHERE job  = '" . $txtJob . "'";
$results2 = sqlsrv_query($connPpp, $query2);?>

<form id="frmpromiseddate" name="frmpromiseddate" action="schedule_job_submit.php" method="POST">
       <table  class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped'>
           <tr>
               <td>Sequence</td>
               <td>Work Center</td>
               <td>Due Date</td>
           </tr>
<?php while ($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results2)) {?>
         <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row2['Sequence']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row2['Work_Center']?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="duedate" id="duedate" value="" />    </td>
         </tr>
<?php ;} //End of while ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Change id (`#`) to class (`.`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Jquery` treats `id`as unique identifier and apply on only one element at a time, where as it treats `class` as a group-identifier and can apply to multiple element at a time so change `id` to `class` both in `html` and `Jquery` code:-**

```
<td><input type="text" name="duedate" class="duedate" value="" /></td>
```

And

```
$('.duedate').datetimepicker({
```

Comment: Thanks. That was perfect

Answer (score 1):

Use class(.) instead of id(#) for date picker

Javascript code :

```
$('.duedate').datetimepicker()
```

HTML code: making id unique

```
<?php $i=0;
while ($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results2)) {?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row2['Sequence']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row2['Work_Center']?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="duedate" class="duedate" id="duedate_<?php echo $i;?>" value="" />    </td>
     </tr>
<?php $i++; } //End of while ?>
```

Comment: it's not and keeping the ID around can be useful - for example if OP decided he wanted to add labels to his markup